# bootstrap4 DIV col-12 is mandatory for mobile device?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

bootstrap4 DIV col-12 is mandatory for mobile device?

Without **col-12** in **DIV** it take full width on mobile then why it required?

Comment: no thats not mandatory, using col-12 depends on your website view and how you want it to look like in small devices

Comment: @DeepakVerma if i want full width then mandatory or it takes automatically?

Comment: yes it will autmotically take full width if it is not defined ex: - if you define a div with col-md-6 than it will automatically take col-12 (full size) in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Not required when you're using single - single box. even div width already 100%.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory. **col-12** will take the full width.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Grid system will actually help to make your website responsive to different devices.